# Programação Visual Basic no Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Usando o modo Visual Basic do Excel, estou criando um formulário de cadastro de clientes. Ele possui um botão chamado "*novo*". Neste botão ele adicionaria um valor ao campo Código que está na planilha excel. Porém, quando vou testá-lo ele apresenta a seguinte mensagem:

> Erro em tempo de execução '9': Subscrito fora do intervalo

E quando clico em depurar, ele aponta a seguinte linha de código como 'errada':

`Do Until Sheets("CLIENTES").Cells(linha, 1) = ""`

O que devo fazer para resolver esse problema?

Comment: Qual é o valor de `linha`? Passe o mouse na variável enquanto estiver depurando

Answer (score 2):

O que faltou foi você referenciar o que queria das células, ele não está conseguindo entender por isso o erro.

O correto seria você usar o seguinte:

```
Do Until Sheets("CLIENTES").Cells(linha, 1).Value = ""
'faz alguma coisa
Loop
```

Assim você estará informando que deseja pegar o valor das Célula(linha, 1) que está na Planilha("Clientes")